# Angular route blank page

Tags: angular

FIXED: We have to add into **app.module.ts**  ->  declarations: [WelcomeComponent,DashboardComponent ]

I want to make a route in Angular ,I have make a file app.routes.ts
with this following code

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {WelcomeComponent} from './welcome/welcome.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core'





const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes)


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRouters {

}
```

But if I open my localhost or localhost/welcome or /dashboard , I got a blank page.
Thanks

EDIT : This is my app.modules.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';

import {AppRouters} from './app.routes';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    AppRouters,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Try `localhost:{port_number}/welcome`

Comment: @NicholasK Hello , With port_number is the same, when I delet route params,my first page work on localhost

Comment: Are you importing the `AppRoutes` in your `AppModule`?

Comment: @NicholasK yes i do

Comment: Please share the app.module.ts file. Also does the template of your components have any html content?

Comment: Do you receive any errors on the console? Possible for you to create a stackblitz demo to replicate your issue?

Comment: @NicholasK No error , but it open my index.html page .

Comment: Why do you have 2 imports for routing in your app.module? What is this line `
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';`?

Comment: @NicholasK it was for a test , i'm going to delete one .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202981/discussion-between-nicholas-k-and-devlogin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the components in your app.modules.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],

  ...

})
export class AppModule { }
```